# Redirectmatch without append parameters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

If you go to these URL: 
http://www.borrat.com/iweb/es/comprar-barco-begur-venta-embarcaciones-costa-brava.htm

We need a redirection 301 to:

[...]/iweb/es/comprar-barco-begur-costa-brava.htm

If I use these expresion:

RedirectMatch /iweb/es/comprar-barco-emporda-venta-embarcaciones-costa-brava.htm /iweb/es/comprar-barco-emporda-costa-brava.htm?

The redirect URL finish with (?)

And if I do the same without (?) at the end, the sistem add some parameters from another expression.

Ex: /es/comprar-barco-emporda-costa-brava.htm?parameter=var

Is there any expression to limite the end for a redirection?

Thx and Best regards,

[Manager Costa Brava Boats](http://www.borrat.com/en/)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use mod_rewrite in order to have the query string entirely removed:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^iweb/es/comprar-barco-emporda-venta-embarcaciones-costa-brava\.htm$ /iweb/es/comprar-barco-emporda-costa-brava.htm? [L,R]
```

Comment: Hi Jon...  I have the same problem. Try to open the website www.borrat.com and put these :  /iweb/es/comprar-barco-emporda-venta-embarcaciones-costa-brava.htm. In the redirected URL you get (?). Bes regards